# How to evaluate whether a table's good or bad in a database system?

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, data-modeling, data-analysis

How can we evaluate whether a table's good or bad in a database system?  What aspects do we need to analyse? Can I build a model for doing such evaluation? If yes then how?

Comment: Are you asking about [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)?

Comment: Good or bad are purely subjective in real life and the same would apply to databases as well. Your question's context seems too broad and what you get are opinionated answers.I'm voting to close this. If you have any specific requirement, edit your question and give the details.

Comment: Well, Derby database is good and Oracle is very bad if I need free and  simple in-memory database, but Derby is very bad and Oracle is good if I need replication and some advanced fetures. It all depends on what features you need and how much money do you have. I vote to close this question as "opinion based".

Comment: @krokodilko - the OP isn't asking how to evaluate different database products. Which doesn't mean that the question isn't asking for opinion-based answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non-exhaustive list. For all these questions, *yes* is a good answer and *no* is bad.

1. Does the table serve a clear business function? How well does it fit the application's purpose?
2. Is the table well-named? Are the table's columns well-named? Would a business user understand what they mean?
3. Does the table have a primary key?
4. Does the table have unique constraints on all the business (candidate) keys?
5. Are all the foreign keys defined?
6. Do all the columns with constrained values have a foreign key to a reference data table or a check constraint (or an `enum` for MySQL)?
7. Do all the columns have the correct (strongest) data type?
8. Is the table correctly normalised? (In an OLTP environment that means at least [Boyce-Codd Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyce%E2%80%93Codd_normal_form), things are different in data warehouses.)
9. Is the table free of any columns which hold "smart keys", CSV strings, JSON, XML, different data items whose meaning is dependent on metadata held in another column (or another table), or any other exotic structure which seemed like a good idea at the time but which will incur a legacy of horrible code and data corruption for years after?
10. Are all the columns scalar, using recognised Oracle built-in data types (i.e. no nested tables or user-defined types)?
11. Does the Physical Data Model diagram include the table?
12. Is the table derivable from entities in the Logical Data Model diagram?
13. Do you have scripts of the DDL for the table and its dependent objects? Are those scripts in source control?
14. Does the table conform to whatever modelling and coding standards you have (if any)?
15. Is the table physically implemented properly (e.g. all necessary indexes, index-organized if appropriate, partitioning if appropriate)?
16. Is the table defensible? How comfortable would you be explaining it to another experienced data modeller, database developer or business user?

---

As you can tell, this is an opinionated list (which is why some people have voted to close your question). Some points are rather imprecise. It's probably a long way from the model you were hoping for.

People will want to argue with some of these measures. For instance, the point about non-atomic data structures like JSON. Of course there are times when such structures are appropriate; I once worked on a system which would have been much simpler if we had stored the data in XMLtype columns instead of shredding it into relational tables. But those are isolated cases. Read some of the questions on this site about smart keys, tokenising CSV strings or writing queries against an Entity-Attribute-Value anti-model to understand how much grief these things cause. [First Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) should be a given, and developers who flout it don't deserve to have databases.

Other points are bellwethers. If your organisation doesn't maintain an up-to-date Physical Data Model then it's likely most if not all of your tables are bad (not inevitable, just likely). It's astonishing how many places don't seem to keep their DDL scripts under source control. How do they manage their deployments to test and production? I think prayer features heavily.